# Zip the contents of every sub-folder in a folder in Mac automatically

Tags: macos, finder, automator, script, archive

I have this folder/file structure

```
parent folder
--subfolder1
  -sub-subfolder
  -file1
  -file2
--subfolder2
  -sub-subfolder
  -file1
  -file2
...
```

I want to:

- create zip files from the contents of the subfolders. which means,
  file1, file2, and sub-subfolder will be zipped, but not the enclosing subfolder.
- name each zip file with the name of the folder, like subfolder1.zip,
  subfolder2.zip...

I'd prefer that the zip files remain in the related subfolder so it will be:

```
parent folder
--subfolder1
  -sub-subfolder
  -file1
  -file2
  -subfolder1.zip
--subfolder2
  -sub-subfolder
  -file1
  -file2
  -subfolder2.zip
...
```

I am hoping that it would be possible with Automator but had no success till now.

My searches resulted in solutions that zip every folder individually *with the folder* itself, which in this case is not useful for me. I need the *contents* of the folders to be zipped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want this for just one folder depth level? I mean, is there another folder in subfolder1 ? Also have you seen "create archive action" which *" creates a zip format archive (.zip) from the files specified."* Please post your automator workflow. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63428/create-a-zip-file-using-an-automator-service/63447#63447

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about Automator, but you can easily accomplish this in Terminal.

```
find "parent folder" -type d -depth 1 -execdir sh -c 'cd "$1" && zip -r "$1" .' _ '{}' \;
```

- `find "parent folder" -type d -depth 1` lists all subdirectories of "parent folder" (just run it to see the result)
- `-execdir` executes the part up to the `\;` for each subdirectory found
- `sh -c 'cd "$1" && zip -r "$1" .' _ '{}'` starts a subshell to change into the directory to pack and then zip the content there. The `{}` contains the name of the subdirectory and is the value `$1` will be set to within the subshell, `_` is syntactically required but the actual content is ignored.

Comment: Or to also recurse could add another loop something like `for d in $(find . -type d); do; for f in $(find $d -type f -depth 1); do; zip -r  "${d}/${d##*/}.zip"  "${f}"; done; done` (I copied the `${d##*/}` bit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script))

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for reminding me of `-depth` :-)

Comment: Nice use (again) of `-execdir`. +1

Comment: @nohillside, this could be the most useful answer I got on StackExchange. I mean it.